# How to force rhodecode to invalidate cache after push via ssh

Tags: version-control, mercurial, paster, rhodecode

I am running a rhodecode instance for code review etc. however when I push via ssh, the rhodecode does not see the changeset (unless I do a manual pull from hgweb).

Do I need a incoming hook in the mercurial or something to get rhodecode to work properly?

**EDIT**:

by adding the hook `incoming.rhodecode = python:rhodecode.lib.hooks.log_push_action` I get the stacktrace:

```
remote:   File "/usr/share/mercurial-server/hg-ssh", line 91, in <module>
remote:     dispatch.dispatch(request(['-R', repo, 'serve', '--stdio']))
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 65, in dispatch
remote:     return _runcatch(req)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 88, in _runcatch
remote:     return _dispatch(req)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 741, in _dispatch
remote:     cmdpats, cmdoptions)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 514, in runcommand
remote:     ret = _runcommand(ui, options, cmd, d)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 831, in _runcommand
remote:     return checkargs()
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 802, in checkargs
remote:     return cmdfunc()
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/dispatch.py", line 738, in <lambda>
remote:     d = lambda: util.checksignature(func)(ui, *args, **cmdoptions)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/util.py", line 472, in check
remote:     return func(*args, **kwargs)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/commands.py", line 5211, in serve
remote:     s.serve_forever()
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/sshserver.py", line 94, in serve_forever
remote:     while self.serve_one():
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/sshserver.py", line 112, in serve_one
remote:     rsp = wireproto.dispatch(self.repo, self, cmd)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/wireproto.py", line 351, in dispatch
remote:     return func(repo, proto, *args)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/wireproto.py", line 629, in unbundle
remote:     lock.release()
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/lock.py", line 143, in release
remote:     callback()
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 2452, in runhooks
remote:     source=srctype, url=url)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/localrepo.py", line 386, in hook
remote:     return hook.hook(self.ui, self, name, throw, **args)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hook.py", line 181, in hook
remote:     r = _pythonhook(ui, repo, name, hname, hookfn, args, throw) or r
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hook.py", line 38, in _pythonhook
remote:     obj = __import__(modname)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 95, in _demandimport
remote:     return _import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rhodecode/lib/hooks.py", line 35, in <module>
remote:     from rhodecode.lib.utils import action_logger
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 114, in _demandimport
remote:     mod = _origimport(name, globals, locals)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rhodecode/lib/utils.py", line 55, in <module>
remote:     from rhodecode.model.db import Repository, User, RhodeCodeUi, \
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 114, in _demandimport
remote:     mod = _origimport(name, globals, locals)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rhodecode/model/db.py", line 147, in <module>
remote:     class RhodeCodeSetting(Base, BaseModel):
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative.py", line 1343, in __init__
remote:     _as_declarative(cls, classname, cls.__dict__)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative.py", line 1082, in _as_declarative
remote:     class_mapped = _is_mapped_class(base)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/util.py", line 696, in _is_mapped_class
remote:     manager = attributes.manager_of_class(cls)
remote:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/demandimport.py", line 87, in __getattribute__
remote:     return getattr(self._module, attr)
remote: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'manager_of_class'
abort: unexpected response: empty string
```

Answer (score 3):

RhodeCode uses post-push hooks to invalidate caches of repositories, and store push/pull event in it's journal. You can do few things to overcome this.

- disable vcs_full_cache, and turn down cache expiration to some low number (eg 60seconds)
- call proper RhodeCode hooks when pushing through SSH, i think it's the most proper solution

Comment: what are the hooks I should be calling?

Comment: you can find them in rhodecode.lib.hooks, log_push/log_pull, make sure you set the proper OS ENV, read the code of hooks to see.

Comment: please see my updated question - the (only) hooks available produce a stack trace - I assume this is because my OS_ENV is not properly set, but I can not find any clues what should be set

Comment: Bounty was awarded since there were no other answers, still looking for an answer to the follow-up question about the stacktrace / OS_ENV.

Comment: No, it looks like there's some other problem with mercurial. I recommend writing a simple python hook, that will call rhodecode hook.
It looks for me that it somehow doesn't like it when called directly.

missing OS_ENV data would raise different error, but inside rhodecode itself.